# Java - Casting an Object to a ByteArrayEntity (Android) ClassCastException

Tags: android, casting, classcastexception

I have a ByteArrayEntity as follows:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
tempPic.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
photoByteArray = new ByteArrayEntity(bitmapdata);
```

`tempPic` is of type `android.graphics.Bitmap`.

What I then have to do is make a request using an AsyncTask that takes an array of `Objects` which I later then cast to their various types.  However, when attempting to cast my ByteArrayEntity later on, I get a `ClassCastException`, I was wondering if anyone could explain this?

```
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Object... httpRequest) 
{
    ByteArrayEntity dataPhoto = null;

    // Further code


    if(myCondition)
    {
        dataPhoto = (ByteArrayEntity)httpRequest[2];
    }

}
```

I really need to get this working, but don't really have time currently to reimplement this completely, so any hacks or workarounds would be appreciated.  I'm working with **Android 2.2**

The whole aim is to take an image from the Android camera, then `setEntity` of my `HttpRequest` to a `ByteArrayEntity` and `POST` my image to a server where this is then handled.

Comment: Are you 100% sure httpRequest[2] is a ByteArrayEntity? I don't think there's anything about any particular class that could prevent casting to it.

Comment: I am 100% sure, I did a System.out.println of httpRequest[2].getClass() and it output "org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity".  Is it something to do with how I declare it?  Just a variable of type ByteArrayEntity that is initialized null?  Should I be creating an Object of it with an empty byte[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing an `Object[]` and then casting based on the position in the array, why not just pass a bean?

```
public class MyBean {
    private ByteArrayEntity myByteArrayEntity;
    private String someString;

    // getters and setters
}
```

No casting required and much easier to maintain/extend.

Comment: This will require a bit more refactoring than is practical at this stage in my project.  I will definitely consider this approach in the future, it is sensible.  Any suggestions on why this casting is failing, though?  It is really strange.

Comment: @Tim It wouldn't really take much refactoring, less than an hour I'd guess. It would also fix your current issue, and prevent similar problems in the future.  In order to see why your current code is failing we would have to see all the code where you ever set an object in the array.  I'd guess you are getting an index wrong at some point.  But as I said, it's much harder to debug an array of objects than a bean.  You'd be much better off just biting the bullet and doing a refactor.  Remember to save a version to source control first!

Comment: I'm still completely stuck as to why the casting doesn't work.  I will use this way... got a long weekend ahead of me.  I'm learning so much as I go on this project, it is a shame I hadn't thought of these concepts initially.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't realize he was trying to pass multiple values of differing types.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a different type parameterization of `AsyncTask` so that you don't need to cast. If you're using an anonymous class then:

```
new ArrayTask<ByteArrayEntity, Void, HttpResponse>() {
    ...
```

So that you can do:

```
@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(ByteArrayEntity... byteArrays) {
    ...
    dataPhoto = byteArrays[2];
    ...
```

if your arguments are indeed intended to be of type `ByteArrayEntity`.

Comment: This would work but my call at the moment takes an array of objects, because when I make the call, I pass a few strings and and entities and maps and then cast them later on depending on their position in the array.  All of them work (the strings and maps) but the ByteArrayEntity won't cast - any ideas?

Comment: Yikes. You really need to do what dave.c says in that case. You should rely on the java type system.